# Adding white border and shadow to Custom Android ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I know this question has been asked before but I have struggled to come up with a solution.

I have a custom ImageView with complete rounded corners which is done programmatically.

I have something like this

[image]

But I want to get to something like this:

[image]

Here is my custom ImageView class.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MLRoundedImageView extends ImageView {

private Context context;

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;

}

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

I know there is just a few extra I need to add i don't want to recreate the entire class as my project is heavily depended on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use layer list:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Basically create a white circle with the dimension you want and use layer list to create it under the picture